# Как узнать координаты точки на экране pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Допустим мне нужно кликнуть на некоторую точку на экране, как узнать её координаты для её добавления в python (pyautogui) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модуль win32api устанавливается при помощи pip install pypiwin32

```
import win32api

print (win32api.GetCursorPos())
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию position модуля pyautogui:

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
```